# Resume Firebase from localStorage

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase+Ionic(AngularFire) to create a mobile iOs/Android app, and it works great. The only problem with using Firebase is that all the content in the app is being downloaded anew every time the user starts.

In an ideal world the app would save the Firebase-content to localStorage, and the next time the user starts the app, it would load from localStorage - and then simply "update" with Firebase to fetch the latest changes.

In other words we would load data locally and "resume" our Firebase-connection. Is this possible?

Note: Although we use AngularFire, the mobile app does not write data - it only reads from the Firebase.

Answer (score 1):

On Android and iOS, Firebase supports [disk persistence](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/offline-capabilities.html#section-enabling-offline-support), which allows the cache to survive app restarts. This feature is currently not available for [JavaScript environments](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/offline-capabilities.html), such as Ionic.

Comment: Untill they release this for the web-version, it would be nice if there was a way to fix this by saving the contents to localStorage. In my case I don't need to enable write-operations while offline, simply to load the locally stored data.